# How to run epydoc gui for win7?

Tags: windows-7, epydoc

The epydoc documentation says:
`The graphical interface can be invoked with the epydocgui command, or with epydoc.pyw in the Scripts subdirectory of the Python installation directory under Windows.`

I've tried running the `epydoc.pyw` file directly, and calling it from command line i.e. `>>> python epydoc.pyw` and `>>> epydoc.pyw`, both from the scripts directory in my python directory.

How am I supposed to run `epydoc.pyw`?

Comment: I figured it out.  I had to run `python path\to\epydoc.pyw` and run that.  I was confused because the epydoc tutorial just uses `epydoc <args>` for its examples.  I guess I'd have to make a batch script called "epydoc.bat" somewhere on my path to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the gui of epydoc, click double on the file epydoc.pyw which is often located at C:\Python27\Scripts

Regarding your question in the comments: 1) open a normal console, 2) navigate to your Script folder and 3) then call the following e.g. to generate uml diagramm. See commandline [documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-reference.html#command-line-usage)

```
python epydoc.py --pdf --graph=umlclasstree Path/To/package
```